# ¿Cómo agrego un if a este método para validar que solo si existe el código cargue la tabla y sino existe el código muestre un mensaje de error:

Tags: validación

Este es el código que utilizo actualmente:

```
private void buscarnotadetalle() {
    try {
        con.conectar();
        rs2 = con.EjecutarConsulta("select * from pedven_det where pedven_cod = " + jTextField1.getText());

        while (rs2.next()) {
            jTextField11.setText(rs2.getString("items_cod"));
            jTextField14.setText(rs2.getString("cantidad"));
            buscar_itemdetalle();
            modelo.addRow(registro);
            modelo.setValueAt(jTextField11.getText(), fila, 0);
            modelo.setValueAt(jTextField12.getText(), fila, 1);
            modelo.setValueAt(jTextField14.getText(), fila, 2);
            jTextField11.setText(null);
            jTextField12.setText(null);
            jTextField14.setText(null);
            jTextField11.requestFocus();
            fila++;
        }
    }

    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(grupos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Si el objeto que devuelve `EjecutarConsulta` es un `resultSet` puedes intentar con este código:

```
boolean tieneFilas = rs2.first() && rs2.next();
```

o bien

```
boolean isEmpty = !rs2.first();
```

y utilizarlos así:

```
private void buscarnotadetalle() {
    try {
        con.conectar();
        rs2 = con.EjecutarConsulta("select * from pedven_det where pedven_cod = " + jTextField1.getText());
        boolean tieneFilas = rs2.first() && rs2.next();
        // o
        boolean isEmpty = !rs2.first();

        if (tieneFilas) {
        // o
        if (!isEmpty) {
            while (rs2.next()) {
                jTextField11.setText(rs2.getString("items_cod"));
                jTextField14.setText(rs2.getString("cantidad"));
                buscar_itemdetalle();
                modelo.addRow(registro);
                modelo.setValueAt(jTextField11.getText(), fila, 0);
                modelo.setValueAt(jTextField12.getText(), fila, 1);
                modelo.setValueAt(jTextField14.getText(), fila, 2);
                jTextField11.setText(null);
                jTextField12.setText(null);
                jTextField14.setText(null);
                jTextField11.requestFocus();
                fila++;
            }
        }
        else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "La consulta no devolvió resultados.", "Aviso", JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
        }
    }

    catch (SQLException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(grupos.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }
}
```

(Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2591732/how-to-check-if-resultset-has-one-row-or-more#2591776)

Answer (score 0):

Antes de ejecutar el `while`, consulta si la variable `rs2` tiene datos.

Algo así como:

```
if (rs2.Count > 0) {
   // Coloca aquí tu WHILE.
} else {
   // Coloca aquí tu mensaje de error.
}
```